# newly created SPL-tokens are not displaying in phantom

Tags: spl-token, metadata, cli

I created some SPL-tokens via `spl-token create-token ...`, and applied some metadata (name, symbol, description, image) via `metaboss create metadata ...`.  They appear correctly on solscan, but are not appearing in the phantom wallet.

https://solscan.io/token/KEYCSagFRRZFzyNrEYVWmTZ9kEDPpvKYcDMwLax3j2M

Here is one of the recent ones.  Am I missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it is very probably a cache issue, i think if you wait a little bit phantom should be able to display it properly. If not, if i were you i would look how the json metadata file is built, may be phantom is looking for an attribute which can't be found

Comment: It's been a day, and they still aren't appearing in the phantom wallet.  Solflare displays them, but only gives the option to send all or none.  It shows up perfect in all of the explorers. I'll start digging through the metadata files and post an update

Comment: if it has 0 decimals, have you checked in the second tab of phantom ? (where nfts are). I thought the name was not appearing, not the token itself.

Answer (score 0):

I imported it in slope wallet, and it got imported, so I think it's some phantom wallet issue/condition for token registry

Comment: It displays in solflare, but only gives the option to ned all or none (nothing in between). I believe it has to do with how it handles "0 decimal" tokens.  Phantom doesn't display the token at all.  I'll take a look at slope and backpack. (I've been less and less impressed with phantom lately)